# Make modal gallery and change the image when .onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to make a img gallery where you can click any img and a popup appears with a different img. I have found how to do a modal gallery but I have been having trouble to show a different image when it opens.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="trabajos">
                <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
                <ul id="gallery">
                    <li class="gallery"><img id="myImg" src="./public/design/Who1.jpg" alt="Grand Hotel Budapest poster & postcards" style="width:250px"></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><img id="myImg" src="./public/design/Legibilidad.jpg" alt="Legibilidad, Typography work" style="width:250px"></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><img id="myImg" src="./public/design/puraLuz1.jpg" alt="Pura Luz poster at Microteatro" style="width:250px"></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><img id="myImg" src="./public/design/nightflyers1.jpg" alt="Graphics for the Netflix series Nightflyers" style="width:250px"></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><img id="myImg" src="./public/design/photography.jpg" alt="Photography" style="width:250px"></li>
                </ul>
        

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

            <!-- The Close Button -->
            <span class="close">&times;</span>

            <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

            <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
                // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

        var urls=["./public/design/Who2.png", "./public/design/legibilidad2.png", "./public/design/puraLuz2.png", "./public/design/nightflyers2.png", "./public/design/fotografia2.png"];
        
        for(j=0; j<urls.length; j++){
                function changeImage() {
                img.src = urls[j];
            }    
        }
        for(i=0; i<img.length; i++){
            img[i].onclick = function(){
                changeImage();
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
                captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                
            }
        }

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
```

Thank you for your time! I really appreciate it

Comment: Hey there, would you be able to create a working example? Stack Overflow provides a way to include HTML, CSS & JavaScript (plus any dependencies) into a runnable example. From there, I'd be able to better understand the code.

To better understand what you're trying to do, would you be able to share a screenshot of the desired state before and after clicking on an image?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code snippet that maybe does what you're looking for, albeit in an opinionated way.

The idea here is that we can store the alternate image that you'd like to use within the modal in the HTML directly, instead of in JavaScript. The reason I did this instead is because I believe it might a bit easier to read the code and if you'd like to change things, it's a bit easier to do that as well.

If you have any specific questions, I'm happy to add more details as needed.

```js
var gallery = document.querySelector("ul")
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var closeButton = document.querySelector("button");

gallery.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // the event.target could be the `li` or the `img`, but we only want the `img`
  var image = event.target.closest('li').querySelector('img')
  
  modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;')
  modal.querySelector('.modal-content').setAttribute('src', image.getAttribute('data-modal-src'))
  
})

closeButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  modal.removeAttribute('style')
})
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

ul li:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

ul li img {
  width: 250px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.modal-content {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="trabajos">
   <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
   <ul>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-modal-src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450" alt="Grand Hotel Budapest poster & postcards"></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-modal-src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450" alt="Legibilidad, Typography work"></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-modal-src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450" alt="Pura Luz poster at Microteatro"></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-modal-src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450" alt="Graphics for the Netflix series Nightflyers"></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-modal-src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450" alt="Photography"></li>
   </ul>
   <!-- The Modal -->
   <div class="modal">
      <!-- The Close Button -->
      <button class="close">&times;</button>
      <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
      <img class="modal-content">
      <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
      <div class="caption"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Reall really appreciate it!